# dompdf and php (mysql data)

Tags: php, mysql, html, dompdf

I would like to pull data from a mysql db.
This data is then inserted into a html file which is then converted to a pdf using **dompdf**.

The template is perfect and display's well when I run call dompdf.

However as soon as I try and insert php code, the template still shows perfectly, how ever the php code is displays nothing. If I open the page its shows, so I know it works.

In the options file I have done this :

```
private $isPhpEnabled = true;
```

my php file to call the template (LeaseBase.php):

```
<?php
$options = new Options(); $options->set('isPhpEnabled','true');


$leasefile = file_get_contents("Leases/LeaseBase.php"); 
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options); $dompdf->loadHtml($leasefile);


$dompdf->stream(); $output = $dompdf->output(); file_put_contents('Leases/NewLeases.pdf', $output);

?>
```

I also can't seem to pick up anything in the log files.

Any assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> However as soon as I try and insert php code, the template still shows
>   perfectly, how ever the php code is displays nothing.

**Answer:** It shows nothing because when a php page is executed, it outputs html (and not the php code). If you don't have an `echo` or `print` or any code that generates html code from the php script, the page will in fact be blank.

It's important to remember that **php** is serverside code WHICH CAN generate html code as long as you instruct it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

With versions of Dompdf prior to 0.6.1 you could load a PHP document and the PHP would be processed prior to rendering. Starting with version 0.6.1 Dompdf no longer parses PHP at run time. This means that if you have a PHP-based document you have to pre-render it to HTML, which does not happen when using `file_get_contents()`.

You have two options:

First: Use output buffering to capture the rendered PHP.

```
ob_start();
require "Leases/LeaseBase.php";
$leasefile = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Second: Fetch the PHP file via your web server:

```
$leasefile = file_get_contents('http://example.com/Leases/Leasebase.php');
```

...though, actually, if I were loading the file into a variable and feeding it to dompdf without doing any further manipulation I would use dompdf to fetch the file instead. In this way you are less likely to have to deal with external resource (images, stylesheets) reference problems:

```
$dompdf->load_html_file('http://example.com/Leases/Leasebase.php');
```